# Regex for capturing City State Zip from an Address String

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex statement that will match only the City, State, and Zip portion of an address.  Here are a few examples of the Addresses I'm working with.

```
3333 Josephine AVE #114 Temecula, CA 99999
11111 MERIT CIR #113 Laguna Hills, CA 99999
```

I currently have the following pattern.

```
[\,].*
```

But This only captures everything pass the comma separating City and State.

Is there a way to also capture the string [City] before the comma that will also work for situations where the City is 2 words (i.e. Los Angeles).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not reliably, no. When you have irregular or bad data, there are no short cuts. It would be better to regenerate the data in CSV or some parseable format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex captures the city, state and zip in groups 1, 2 and 3 respectively:

```
#\d+ ([^,]+), ([A-Z]{2}) (\d{5})
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/Hguo19BE7X).

Comment: That demo is great. Thank you for this. I have spent too much time trying to figure out the address parsing I needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to capture exact states in Regex, or rather it would be a really long regex. However, I did test it out and this is what I came up with

```
/([A-Z][a-z]+\s?)+,\s[A-Z]{2}\s\d{5}-?\d{4}?/
```

It matched this

```
Gfdsdf Gfdsf, CA 43534
```

Here is the breakdown

`()` - This captures the enclosed regular expression

`[A-Z]`- Finds all uppercase letters.

`[a-z]+` - Followed by one or more lower case letters

`\s?` - Followed by an optional space

`+` - This allows us to have multiple words in the city name

`,\s` - This is immediately followed by a comma and a space

`[A-Z]{2}` - The ISO code for states are two letters each. Obviously in this simple example, it would include bogus states, but the regex would be too long otherwise.

`\d{5}` - Ends in a five digit zip code.

`-?\d{4}?` - Optionally matches the zip+4 format. It is not required

Comment: What about ZIP+4? :)

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: It's a standard US format, like `12345-6789`. It's not that your solution is wrong, it's that the OP's corpus is really limited and not representative of  real-world data. The whole thing is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Understood. It was easy enough to add a condition to this regex

Comment: I'm a bit confused why it doesn't match `FENTON, MO 63206`. The last ZIP+4 section should be optional but it fails unless it's there for me...

Answer (score 1):

Given just your corpus, which always has a suite/apartment number, you can do it with:

```
$ echo '3333 Josephine AVE #114 Temecula, CA 99999
11111 MERIT CIR #113 Laguna Hills, CA 99999' |
pcregrep -o '#\d+ \K.*'
Temecula, CA 99999
Laguna Hills, CA 99999
```

However, if you have irregular data that isn't in a well-defined format like CSV, you will have problems. For example, what about addresses with two or more words in the street name, or addresses that don't have an apartment number?

The real solution is to regenerate your data using a standardized format like CSV. If you can't do that, then parse just conforming data (e.g. lines with 7 fields) and then eyeball the hopefully-small remainder.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are better ways to do this but you can try to use this:

## (\d*)\s+((?:[\w+\s*-])+)[\,]\s+([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([0-9a-zA-Z]+)

Group 1: Apt/House number

Group 2: City (Could have multiple spaces, underscores and dashes)

Group 3: State/Province code

Group 4: Postal Code (Could be made of letters and numbers)

This will match all the following cases: 
3333 Josephine AVE #114 Temecula, CA 99

11111 MERIT CIR #113 Laguna Hills, CA 99999

11111 MERIT CIR #113 ddwwqs Laguna Hills, CA 99999

11111 MERIT CIR #113 sss  ssss sss xs, CA 99999

11111 MERIT CIR #113 hkjkhuhuh, CAdsdsd T3B2R1

11111 MERIT CIR #113 dsadsa-ddasdas , CAdsdsd T2N21T

See a demo here: http://www.regexr.com/3cuds